# Different queryset optimisation for list view and change view in Django Admin

Tags: django-admin

The `get_queryset` method for an admin model can be overridden; I use it to select/prefetch objects that are `OneToOneField`s or `ManyToManyField`s. However, the list view for my model shows only concise information while the change view contains many more objects. It would not make sense to prefetch `ManyToManyField` relations in the list view if these will not be displayed anyway.

Sample model:

```py
class Location(TimeStampedModel):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('Profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    postcode = models.CharField("postcode", max_length=11, blank=True)
    tenants = models.ManyToManyField('Profile', blank=True)
```

Sample admin model:

```py
@admin.register(Location)
class LocationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('owner', 'postcode')
    fields = ('owner', 'postcode', 'tenants')
    filter_horizontal = ('tenants',)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(LocationAdmin, self).get_queryset(request).select_related('owner__user')
        qs = qs.prefetch_related('tenants')
        return qs
```

Is it possible to define different optimisations for the queryset returned for the list view of the model and the queryset returned for the change/add view of the same model?

That is, in the sample admin model above, the `qs.prefetch_related('tenants')` line will be relevant for the change/add view only?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to use the `request.resolver_match` attribute which can be used to work out which view you are executing. The following is slightly hacky/fragile (it is essentially using some internals), but works:

```py
class LocationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['owner', 'postcode']
    fields = ['owner', 'postcode', 'tenants']
    filter_horizontal = ['tenants']

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(LocationAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        qs = qs.select_related('owner__user')
        if request.resolver_match.func.__name__ == 'change_view':
            qs = qs.prefetch_related('tenants')
        return qs
```

You should also consider whether you need this and whether it will actually work. The change view shows only one main object, which means that the N+1 problem for a list of objects often does not apply. In addition, the queries for inlines and the widgets for foreign key and many-to-many fields may not use the querysets you provide from `get_queryset`. For this case, testing with Django 1.10.2, the `prefetch_related` call did not reduce the number of queries the 'change' view executed. The 'add' view did not use the `get_queryset` method at all.

See complete demo app at https://github.com/spookylukey/djangoadmintips/tree/master/queryset_optimization

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense that the `add` view does not use `get_queryset`... In my case the horizontal widget for `tenants` was causing a separate query for each `User` in the system (4000 users = 4000 additional queries) so the `prefetch_related` and `select_related` were quite an optimisation. That was because the `__str__` method of `Profile` was relying on some information in the `User` model.

Comment: how "hacky" is this method you are proposing? won't it break in the next release of Django? meanwhile I’ve overridden `change_view`, `add_view`, and `changelist_view` functions in order to provide for the different optimisations.

Comment: To fix the `__str__` method of `Profile`, you could also add the `prefetch_related` call into a default manager `get_queryset` method.

Comment: Regarding hackiness - the only thing this depends on is the name of the `change_view` function, which is unlikely to change. You could also add some more asserts to check that the method name is one of the options you expect it to be, so if it breaks you will know.

Comment: BTW, could you upvote/accept the answer if it works for you?